# Combining two resized (matched sizes) images together with image magick

Tags: vb.net, image, imagemagick

I have two images I want to combine together with image magick. The way I have it setup right now is a form will upload an image to a server, resize the image to make a smaller version, then save both to a folder. I have my code setup correctly for this using image magick and it works just fine.

What I'm looking to accomplish is *sort of* like annotating it, however I'd like to do this by appending a header image to the top of the file. I know I can accomplish this using the -append flag. What I'm confused on is how I can match the image sizes so I don't need to do several resizes.

I'm making the resizing occur only if the uploaded files exceed 1000x1000 (using the -resize 1000x1000> argument), but this doesn't guarantee that all files will be 1000px wide. I've made the header image 1000 pixels wide, and when the image is at 1000px, appending those is no problem.

My problem is deciphering how it should be handled when it's smaller than that. Do I resize the header image to the other images size, then append? I know it'd be better to avoid scaling the image up to 1000px, then appending the header and scaling back down, as that would affect image quality. Can I resize the header image *without* writing it to a temporary file? Like, chain the events and only end up writing a single completed file to disk?